# Can't find missing key in 'Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop'

Tags: reactjs

I've been starring at my code, but I can't see where the key is missing. That is my error:
**Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
Check the render method of `Card`. It was passed a child from ContractInfo.**

Here is Card:

```
export const Card = ({ selected, onChange, title, price, frequency, description, feature, cta }) => {
  const mode = selected ? 'border-yellow-500 border-4' : 'border-gray-200'
  
  return (
    <div
      className={["relative p-8 bg-white border-gray-200 rounded-2xl shadow-sm flex flex-col border-2", mode].join(' ')}
      style={{cursor:'pointer'}}
      selected={selected}
      onClick={onChange}
    >
      <div className="flex-1 ">
        <h3 className="text-xl font-semibold text-gray-900">{title}</h3>
        <p className="mt-4 flex items-baseline text-gray-900">
          <span className="text-5xl font-extrabold tracking-tight">€{price}</span>
          <span className="ml-1 text-xl font-semibold">{frequency}</span>
        </p>
        <p className="mt-6 text-gray-500">{description}</p>
        {/* Feature list */}
        {feature}
      </div>
      <div className= 'bg-yellow-500 text-white hover:bg-yellow-600 mt-8 block w-full py-3 px-6 border border-transparent rounded-md text-center font-medium'>
        {cta}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And here is the bit in ContractInfo:

```
 return (
    <div className={formStep === 0 ? 'block' : 'hidden'}>
      <div className="bg-white py-16 px-4 overflow-hidden sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
        <div className="relative max-w-xl mx-auto">
          <div className="text-center">
            <h2 className="text-3xl font-extrabold tracking-tight text-gray-600 sm:text-4xl">Welcher Vertrag passt zu dir?</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="max-w-7xl mx-auto py-4 px-4 bg-white sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
          <div className="mt space-y-12 lg:space-y-0 lg:grid lg:grid-cols-3 lg:gap-x-8">
            
            {contracts.map((contract, index) => (
              <Card
                key={contract.id}
                title={contract.title}
                price={contract.price}
                frequency={contract.frequency}
                description={contract.description}
                feature={ contract.features.map((feature, index) =>
                  <ul role="list" className="mt-6 space-y-6">
                    <li className="flex" key={feature.id} >
                      {console.log(feature.id)}
                      <CheckIcon className="flex-shrink-0 w-6 h-6 text-yellow-500" aria-hidden="true" />
                      {feature.name} 
                    </li>
                  </ul> )}
                cta={contract.cta}
                selected={isSelected === index}
                onChange={() => setisSelected(index)}
              />
            ))}
            {/* {console.log(contracts?.[isSelected])} */}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="mt-5 sm:mt-8 sm:flex sm:justify-center lg:justify-center">
          <div className="rounded-md shadow">
            <a role="button" tabIndex={0}
              className="w-full flex items-center justify-center px-8 py-3 border border-transparent text-base font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none md:py-4 md:text-lg md:px-10 cursor-not-allowed"
            >
              Zurück
            </a>
          </div>
          <div className="mt-3 sm:mt-0 sm:ml-3">
            <a
              //onClick={nextQuizStep}
              onClick={() => nextFormStep(contracts?.[isSelected]) }
              className="w-full flex items-center justify-center px-8 py-3 border border-transparent text-base font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-yellow-500 hover:bg-yallow-600 md:py-4 md:text-lg md:px-10"
            >
              Weiter
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Keys are both present for features list and for cards. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Key Error is caused by feature rendering in `Card` component

This is cause the keys are not present among sibling elements of the for loop in feature creation, so to correct this You set key for parent `ul` in

```
        feature={ contract.features.map((feature, index) =>
          <ul role="list" className="mt-6 space-y-6">
            <li className="flex" key={feature.id} >
              {console.log(feature.id)}
              <CheckIcon className="flex-shrink-0 w-6 h-6 text-yellow-500" aria-hidden="true" />
              {feature.name} 
            </li>
          </ul> )}
```

so it becomes

```
        feature={ contract.features.map((feature, index) =>
          <ul role="list" className="mt-6 space-y-6" key={'feature-'+feature.id}>
            <li className="flex" >
              {console.log(feature.id)}
              <CheckIcon className="flex-shrink-0 w-6 h-6 text-yellow-500" aria-hidden="true" />
              {feature.name} 
            </li>
          </ul> )}
```

Comment: `key` error is referring to `<Card />` component.